# Move a pdf from download to external storage folder

Tags: android, pdf, fileoutputstream

I need to move and rename a pdf file.

I am using a file picker to select the pdf which seems to work:

```
File selected = new File(fileList.get(position));    
String myFileString = selected.toString();
```

This gives me a string to an existing file, for example: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/myPdf.pdf"

The next step is an attempt to rename and copy the file to a folder I have set up called tsp:

```
String myRenamedPdf= "myRenamedPdf.pdf";

File fromLocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + myFileString);
File toLocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/tsp/" + MyRenamedPdf);

    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(fromLocation);
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(toLocation);
    FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
    inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
```

When I check, the new file doesnt exist. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You cannot execute that code without having put it in a try catch block. You will have a catch. Inspect e.getMessage().

Comment: Why are you introducing File fromLcation where you already have File selected? Use that!

Comment: Those comments fixed it, thank you.